# How to change the window manager's mouse click actions?

Tags: mouse, gala

When I click with the middle button of the mouse on a window, it goes to the bottom of the stack, and two clicks on the window bar maximize it. Can we change that? or even disable?

**some background:**

I use the middle click to paste content on a new tab on chrome, middle clicking the new tab button, but it's easy to miss it and put your browser on the bottom of the stack, it is annoying

Comment: @tim I would like to disable the middle-click putting the window on the bottom

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use `gsettings`:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'none'
```

Will disable the feature. To re-enable, use this:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences action-middle-click-titlebar 'lower'
```

---

These are the options you can set it to:

- `toggle-shade`, which will shade/unshade the window (roll up / down)
- `toggle-maximize` which will maximise/unmaximise the window
- `toggle-maximize-horizontally` and `toggle-maximize-vertically` which will maximise/unmaximise the window in that direction only
- `minimize` which will minimise the window
- `shade` which will roll the window up
- `menu` which will display the window menu (default for right click)
- `lower` which will put the window behind all the others
- `none` which will not do anything, and effectively disables this action.

Comment: this helps, sadly for chrome there is this bug https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=132061 , but this is the best we can do, I think, thanks!